# Service Account not logging to ULS

Tags: 2013, administration, uls

I have one web application run by the spPortal. I noticed an error was thrown and a correlation id was given to me, but no logs were appearing in ULS for any request to this web app. I saw that logs were being written for any request to Central Admin, so I changed the broken web app to use the same identity as CA: spFarm. After the change, logs were written. What could be missing from spPortal that would prevent him from logging? I have added him to the Administrators group but saw no change.

This is a single server dev VM.

Comment: How did you change the application pool account, did you add it as a managed service account and change it through SharePoint, or just IIS?

Comment: Both were already managed service accounts. I changed it in IIS.

Comment: You need to change it from the "Configure Service Accounts" page under "Security", if there is no web application pool there that suits you, create a new one using powershell: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607595.aspx Also see here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/denotation/2014/02/27/how-to-change-sharepoint-2013-application-pool-account/

Comment: How many servers in farm? Also check if account has some deny permission on server.